# How to use .netrc when running MKS Toolkit on Windows?

Tags: ftp, mks, .netrc

I am moving an application from Unix (AIX) to Windows. We have MKS Toolkit on the Windows server in order to run our shell scripts fairly unchanged. However, my old FTP jobs depend on the .netrc file. Can anybody tell me whether .netrc is supported under MKS Toolkit, and if yes, where to put the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man4/netrc.4.asp :

> The .netrc file is a text file residing in your home directory [...]

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/bsdftp.1.asp

> If auto-login is enabled, bsdftp checks the .netrc file in the user's home directory [...]

Comment: Thanks for the info - but how do change to my home directory in Windows? cd alone doesn't work; neither does cd ~, cd ~/. or cd ~\.

Comment: i assume you are using one of the MKS Toolkit shells and not the Windows shell? then `cd` should work, and also `echo $HOME` for finding your home dir.